# first shape parameter should be null,but it's not allowed

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I have this model:

[image: model I trained]

Which is a conv layer that's suppose to detect facial emotions,
I try to implement it on my TensorFlowJS, so I converted it and when I try to enter an input, it requires a 4d tensor with null as the first input,
but the tensor4d will not allow it:
[image]

The shape should be a number only, but when I try to add it to my model it asks for null, what do I do?
This is the function I convert jpg to tensors:

```
const imageToTensor = (rawData: ArrayBuffer) => {
    const { width, height, data } = jpeg.decode(rawData, true);
    const buffer = new Uint8Array(width * height * 3);
    let offset = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; i += 3) {
      buffer[i] = data[offset]; //red
      buffer[i + 1] = data[offset + 1]; //green
      buffer[i + 2] = data[offset + 2]; //blue
      offset += 4; //skips Alpha value
    }
      //instead of 1 I need null, but wont let me -----
    return tf.tensor4d(buffer, [1, height, width, 3]);
  };
```

EDIT: this is my prediction function :

```
const trypredict = async () => {
    try {
      let image = require("../assets/smile.jpg");
      image = tf.browser
        .fromPixels(image)
        .mean(2)
        .toFloat()
        .expandDims(0)
        .expandDims(-1);
      const imageAssetPath = Image.resolveAssetSource(image);
      const response = await fetch(imageAssetPath.uri, {}, { isBinary: true });
      const imageData = await response.arrayBuffer();

      let imageTensor = imageToTensor(imageData);
      imageTensor = imageTensor.resizeBilinear([48, 48]);
      if (model) {
        const prediction = await model.predict(imageTensor);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Could you print out the shape of the tensor when it comes out from the function above? Also are you using this in a react native app?

Comment: I think you completely misunderstood my answer to your other question, None here it means it can be any value, not that it has to be null. In your case using 1 is completely fine and it is the intended correct value!

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy that's what happens when I do that: 
Error when checking : expected conv2d_8_input to have shape [null,48,48,1] but got array with shape [1,560,617,3].

Comment: @yuRa the error kinda shows the shape, its in react native : 
Error when checking : expected conv2d_8_input to have shape [null,48,48,1] but got array with shape [1,560,617,3].
 what do you think?

Comment: The image has to be 48x48 with one channel, while your image is 560x617 with three channels, you need to resize the image and convert to grayscale. The error has nothing to do with the first dimension.

Comment: Yes you need to resize it as @Dr. Snoopy mentioned. You can use ```tf.resizeBillinear() ```

Comment: may I have the correct syntax on how do I resize it to 48x48? or maybe a tutorial?

Comment: I will add an answer.

Comment: Your model takes in grayscale images so you would have to convert the tensor to a grayscale image first then resize it.

Comment: @yuRa what is the syntax to do that? the tensorflow js library is so new I can't find any material at all on this.

Comment: I added in an answer with 2 methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to resize the tensor from `[1,560, 617,3]` to `[null,48,48,1]`

But your model takes in greyscale images so you need to convert it from RGB to greyscale first:

**Method 1**

```
tf.browser.fromPixels(image)
    .mean(2)
    .toFloat()
    .expandDims(0)
    .expandDims(-1)
```

Then you can resize it.

The array for the second parameter represents the `[newHeight,newWidth]`.

The tensor is the tensor you want to resize to a new shape which would be the greyscale image.

```
 const alignCorners = true;
 const imageResize = tf.image.resizeBilinear(
          tensor,
          [48, 48],
          alignCorners
        );
```

**Method 2**

Or an easier way would be to use [cameraWithTensor](https://js.tensorflow.org/api_react_native/0.3.0/#cameraWithTensors) and resize the tensor immediately. You can do so using the following then after that you would just have to reshape it to a 4D tensor:

```
return <View>
      <TensorCamera
       // Standard Camera props
       style={styles.camera}
       type={Camera.Constants.Type.front}
       // Tensor related props
       cameraTextureHeight={textureDims.height}
       cameraTextureWidth={textureDims.width}
       resizeHeight={48}
       resizeWidth={48}
       resizeDepth={1}
       onReady={this.handleCameraStream}
       autorender={true}
      />
    </View>
```

Then you can reshape it into a 4D tensor:

```
image = image.reshape(1,48,48,1)
```

[Here is a code example using cameraWithTensor with detailed code for it](https://github.com/tafsiri/tfjs-expo-managed-example/blob/master/App.js)

Comment: thanks for the help, but regarding first method when do I need to transform it to grayscale, right after I fetched the photo? because I get this error : pixels passed to tf.browser.fromPixels() must be either an HTMLVideoElement, HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, ImageData in browser, or OffscreenCanvas, ImageData in webworker or {data: Uint32Array, width: number, height: number}, but was Number , I pass it the image that I required

Comment: I added the code to my original post , so it will be clearer